# Create State from another context state in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to get a state from context and initialize to new state. But the newly created state is not initializing. Help me out.

```
import { ProductsContext } from "../../../store/ProductsContext";


const EditVariant = () => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { getProductsById, singleProduct } = useContext(ProductsContext);

  const [productName, setProductName] = useState(singleProduct.productName);
  console.log(productName)  // This is undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductsById(id);
  }, []);

  return (

          <Form
            productName={productName}
            setProductName={setProductName}
          /> 
   
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditVariant;
```

The Form component gets the undefined value. The value is not initializing properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your UserContext so it can be imported into the components that need it:

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Name');

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ name, setName }}>
      <Home />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Afterward, you can import it into your desired component:

```
import { UserContext } '../../App'

function Home() {
    const user = useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <>
            <label>Your name:</label>
            <input type='text' onChange={e => user.setName(e.target.value)} />
            <p>{user.name}</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I have already exported the my context data

Answer (score 0):

It might be because singleProduct.productName was undefiend in initial and get value later so you can  simply set that in useEffect like this:

```
  const { getProductsById, singleProduct } = useContext(ProductsContext);

  const [productName, setProductName] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(singleProduct.productName){
      setProductName(singleProduct.productName)
    }
  },[singleProduct])
```

Comment: This  Works, But not all time. After creating new state, am passing the new state to another component. Sometimes the new component wont getting values.

Comment: why passing state ? why you are not using context in another component too?

Comment: The new component is a form to update the data. I want to show the existing value in the input fields and i want to change the value when user types in using state in onChange function. Any idea how to implement this?